# Hybrid (List+Dict) container in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, std, hybrid

Is it possible to provide std::map and std::vector capabilities within the same class?

If not, what is the obstacle?

Please note that I have no experience working with stdlib, so I apologise in advance if this is a stupid idea to even consider.  I would like to present my scenario below, so that the reader can see why I am considering this alternative:

---

I am in the final stages of rewriting a C++ wrapper around the Python runtime. The idea is that my C++ project is able to execute Python scripts.

In Python everything is a `PyObject`, and I have an `Object` class wrapping a `PyObject*` which could be pointing to any of a dozen of Python's inbuilt Types (boolean, integer, floatingpoint, unicode, bytes, set, list, tuple, dictionary, callable, module).

I would like to mirror Python's chameleon typing in C++.

So if the wrapped PyObject is {set, list, bytes, unicode, tuple} these are all sequences, so I would like to be able to do things like:

```
cout << my_seq[3]
my_seq[4] = foo
for( auto item : my_seq ) {...}
```

And if it is a dictionary, I can do:

```
my_dict["someKey"] = someValue;
for( auto kv_pair : my_seq ) {...}
```

etc.

The original project had a SeqBase class, which contained the necessary stdlib container machinery for fast enumeration etc. begin, end, iterator, const_iterator, etc. And {set, list, bytes, unicode, tuple} derived from this. Code [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cxx/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/CXX/CXX/Python3/Objects.hxx#l1279).

It also had a MapBase class, which contained a different begin, end, iterator, const_iterator, etc. Code [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cxx/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/CXX/CXX/Python3/Objects.hxx#l2635).

I would like to amalgamate these two containers, so that everything can still be handled from a single Object class.

But I'm not at all sure whether it is possible.

An immediate obstacle I can see is:

```
// SeqBase
typedef size_t size_type;
typedef seqref<T> reference;
typedef T const_reference;
typedef seqref<T> *pointer;
typedef int difference_type;
typedef T value_type; // TMM: 26Jun'01

// MapBase
typedef size_t size_type;
typedef Object key_type;
typedef mapref<T> data_type;
typedef std::pair< const T, T > value_type;
typedef std::pair< const T, mapref<T> > reference;
typedef const std::pair< const T, const T > const_reference;
typedef std::pair< const T, mapref<T> > pointer;
```

It looks like these typedefs need to exist in order for stdlib algorithms to process the object. But it looks as though I would need to choose either one set or the other.
Four example, the pointer typedef is different in both of those cases.

What solutions might there be?

Maybe I could template Object, and use metaprogramming to allow Object and Object, maybe use SFINAE to switch the relevant iterators in and out.

This looks probably worse than subclassing, but I would like to see all the options I have.

I'm still wondering whether there is some way to do it without needing to specify in advance.

I'm not concerned about producing code that could be misused, it is the consumer's responsibility not to do dictionary-things on a list, etc.

(NOTE: as an aside, I've already cracked the problem of using `A["key"] = B[42]` type syntax for sequence type objects and dictionaries. The only obvious problem I'm facing is that I would like to enable fast enumeration: `for(auto item:my_obj)`, but I haven't yet focused on the end use, and I would like to pre-empt common usage scenarios).

Comment: All you need to to be able to provide a `begin` and `end` function, and all you need for those is to be able to provide a custom iterator. See: http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterator-define.html

Comment: What is it you want to do exactly? Is the Python bit relevant to the question?

Comment: I can't parse "a C++ Python wrapper" - Which language is wrapping which?

Comment: If I understand correctly you just want an always sorted std::vector with optimized find using std::lower_bound. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something crucial, Boost.Container provides a [flat_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx) which is basically a map built on top of a vector.

Unless you have pinpointed a normal (unordered_)map as a slow point in your program, I'd hesitate to move away from it though...